# How to upload .apk version to beta channel

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've an application which has two product flavors:

1. production
2. development

Current .apk version published inside play store is with version code 40 and it's production flavor, so the package looks something like this: "example.smth.app". I've released a new functionality in development environment and I want to fully test billing inside my android application. I cannot receive SKUs, because I run the code with development flavor and that's normal as I have to post development version to access SKUs list.

Well, I made an .apk for development environment. It has version code 36. I got an message that:

1. Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name "example.smth.app".
2. You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 40.

Well, I could just solve the second point by changing the version code of .apk from 37 to 40 and that would resolve this, I guess, but what to do with the first point?

For development apks we have package name like this: "example.smth.app.dev" - does this mean that it's not possible to post this .apk to beta channel?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. The beta channel has the same package name as all other channels. The package name is fix for the app.